# No "Access-Control-Allow-Oriign" header is present on the requested resource — localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, cors

I've tried what feels like every answer on Stack Overflow regarding CORS and React, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I want to run React on localhost:3000 and Express on localhost:9090, then post some data from React to Express, and get back a message that says the server got the data.

I always get this error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

In my server I have two files involved in this:

**api.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("API is working properly");
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.send("result gotten!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

// Require routes
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var apiRouter = require('./routes/api'); 

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Tell express to use specific routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter); 

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

In my client I have **SchoolForm.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

class SchoolForm extends Component {
    /* https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("Form was submitted with value " + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(this.current);

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9090/api', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
                     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"},
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    School:
                    <input type="text" name="schoolName" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default SchoolForm;
```

I've also tried setting the proxy in my client's package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "maps-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9090",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get past this CORS block??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install cors package

```
npm i --save cors
```

Then in your express app,

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

or else you can also add cors() to selected routes,

For example,

```
app.get('/', cors(), (req,res) => {})
```

Also you can pass cors options & configurations. To see available options please check the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Note - If you need to add a proxy server for development process with `create-react-app`, try the [manual approach](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually).